# Same Youtube query, different customUrl value

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have been running into non-deterministic results from the Youtube V3 API for channel.list. To demonstrate this, I can make 2-3 queries in a row and get different results for the customUrl field:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2Ccontent_details%2Cstatistics%2Cbranding_settings&id=UC5YMTGTO7q3BdgtAHsbp6BQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
"title": "3M Health Care",
"description": "Helping healthcare professionals improve patient outcomes across the continuum of care, from the hospital to the clinic, long-term facility to home, with medical supplies and clinical expertise you can rely on.",
"customUrl": "3MSkinWound",
"publishedAt": "2010-02-15T23:44:27.000Z",
```

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2Ccontent_details%2Cstatistics%2Cbranding_settings&id=UC5YMTGTO7q3BdgtAHsbp6BQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
"title": "3M Health Care",
"description": "Helping healthcare professionals improve patient outcomes across the continuum of care, from the hospital to the clinic, long-term facility to home, with medical supplies and clinical expertise you can rely on.",
"customUrl": "3mhealthcare",
"publishedAt": "2010-02-15T23:44:27.000Z",
```

This should be deterministic. If I ask for the customUrl for UC5YMTGTO7q3BdgtAHsbp6BQ it should always come back as the same value. To me, this is an obvious bug. Can anyone detect that we are doing something wrong or that know of a way to avoid this non-determinism?

PS: I guess I should note that the customUrl="3MSkinWound" seems to refer to [/user/3MSkinWound](https://www.youtube.com/user/3MSkinWound) (as [/c/3MSkinWound](https://www.youtube.com/c/3MSkinWound) does not exist), while the customUrl="3mhealthcare" refers to [/c/3mhealthcare](https://www.youtube.com/c/3mhealthcare) (as [/user/3mhealthcare](https://www.youtube.com/user/3mhealthcare) does not exist). This seems to be at odds with the [documentation for customUrl](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?hl=en) EXCEPT https://www.youtube.com/3MSkinWound (which redirects to [/user/3MSkinWound](https://www.youtube.com/user/3MSkinWound)) and https://www.youtube.com/3mhealthcare (which does not redirect to a different URL) both work.

Also, as noted in the comment below, I ran 20 consecutive calls on a different channel but got similar results: at a 3:1 ratio, it returned the **/user** customUrl name versus the **/c** customUrl name.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this documentation about [customURL](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, we have and while there are multiple versions allowable, it does not explain why the API is non-deterministic in returning a value. Either return the same value or a list but not a value that depends upon when the call is made.

Comment: I just made twenty consecutive queries for the same channel ID (UCyXz9GtP9jVWqNqu9xXCS7A) and got "3MwPolsce" 15 times and "3mpolska" 5 times, which jives with the approximate 3:1 ratio I see.

Comment: I opened an issue with Google and they say it is "Won't Fix (Infeasible)": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144236336?pli=1. I have a hard time accepting that a computer system cannot be made to be deterministic but what can we do?